# How could I have improved this question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I asked [a question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60925/allowing-a-minor-under-ones-care-to-be-around-a-suspected-pedophile) recently about a hypothetical scenario where one suspects an individual is a pedophile. It was downvoted several times, with a number of comments accusing me of attempting to get around some law, and a one even calling it "f-ing disgusting" and making rather... repulsive accusations. It was not my intent to push anyone's buttons.

Obviously it is a sensitive topic. How should I have better asked this question to better specify:

1. That this is hypothetical,
2. That I have no intent to break the law, and
3. That I have **absolutely** no intent to put any child under my care in harm's way?

I've added an example and tried to make the title less controversial. What else should I do? In other words, how do I ask a question about what constitutes child abuse without making people think I am trying to find some loophole to allow an someone to abuse a child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as presently written it is OK and wouldn't have attracted the negative reactions of the earlier drafts – especially the original title.

(I do think it could be more effective if you changed the first sentence from saying, "What are the legal ramifications...."  That's a very open-ended phrase.)

Answer (score 1):

Re "*What are the legal ramifications*..." consider editing the first sentence to reflect the meaning of the final one, for example words to the effect:

> What law prevents a parent from allowing their child to visit...?